# on edit fill the form fields with the database values

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have checkbox list in my form where user can select and save the data in to the database and edit the data.

In the checkbox list i have one checkbox named other and if user check the checkbox named other it populates a textbox in which user has to enter the other value.

while saving the data into the database I just replaced other checkbox value with textbox value.so upto now its working good.

But if user wants edit the form, I have to show the checkboxes with mark if value exists in the database and also if there is any value related to other then other checkbox should be checked and i have to place the value in the textbox.

Please find the code below

```
$aEquipment = array("Arthroscopy", "K-wires", "C-arm", "Mini-c-arm", "Other");

        //converting comma separated into array using explode function
        $dbequipment = $event->proc_equipment_request;  //array of values from database
            $dbequipment= explode('|',$dbequipment);
          foreach ($aEquipment as $equipment) {
             if(in_array($equipment,$dbequipment)) {
                    echo "<input name=\"equipment[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$equipment\" CHECKED> $equipment ";
              } else{
                  if($equipment == "Other"){
                         echo "<input name=\"equipment[]\" type=\"checkbox\" id=\"otherEquipment\" value=\"$equipment\"> $equipment";
                         echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"otherEquipmentVal\" name = \"otherEquipment\" style=\"display:none; width:25%;\" placeholder=\"Equipment request\" />";
                     } else {
                         echo "<input name=\"equipment[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$equipment\"> $equipment";
                     }
                }
              }
```

I am able to check the checkboxes but unable to place the value of textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fill the value attribute of the text field, you have now:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"otherEquipmentVal\" name = \"otherEquipment\" style=\"display:none; width:25%;\" placeholder=\"Equipment request\" />";
```

And need to have:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"otherEquipmentVal\" name = \"otherEquipment\" style=\"display:none; width:25%;\" placeholder=\"Equipment request\" value=\"Your Value\" />";
```

Note the difference is the follow attribute at the end:

```
value=\"Your Value\"
```

Comment: I am unable to separate the textbox value from database.

Comment: In which variable you have it and in which format? How do you store it in database?

Comment: $dbequipment holds the array of values like array("Arthroscopy", "K-wires", "C-arm", "Mini-c-arm", "OtherReplacedwithTextBox-value");. I have to check the other checkbox and place the OtherReplacedwithTextBox-value in to the textbox

Comment: then you can do the follow to get the Element number 5 in your list
 
$value_from_db = $dbequipment[4];

then the value can be filled as:

(...) value=\"$value_from_db\" />";